# New Managed Properties don't contain values

Tags: 2013, search, properties, crawl, managed

We are facing a very unusual issue at one of our customers. Newly created managed properties are not being filled with values.

## The scenario:

SharePoint 2013

the Search Service Application has been in action for about 1.5 years and was working well

we need a new refiner in one of the search centers, therefore we went through the following steps:

1. create a new site column (ex: **Country**, single line of text)
2. add it to a document library
3. upload a sample document to the library and fill in values for all fields (value for **Country**: *Canada*)
4. start an incremental crawl (this automatically creates a crawled and a managed property, let's assume that the managed property is called: **MPCountry**)
5. after making sure, that the managed property is properly mapped to the crawled property, we started a full crawl (this should ensure, that the newly created managed property contain the values from documents metadata)

## The result:

By searching for *Canada*, the sample document can be found!
By searching for **MPCountry**:*Canada* no document can be found. Furthermore, a single log entry can be found in ULS stating that the managed property cannot be found in the search service application.

## Other interesting findings:

Old managed properties can still be used to filter for documents.
Old managed properties are filled with values from newly uploaded documents.

Comment: What are the "Old managed properties"? When you look at the attributes of the MPCountry property, is it Queryable?

Comment: By "old managed properties" I mean those properties, which we have added in the past. Of course, MPCountry is queriable, searchable, retreivable, etc. (all relevant checkboxes are set).

Comment: OK, is the Site Column/Managed Property declared in the same site collection as the Search Center? Or are they two separate site collections? I have been meaning to test this.

Comment: I've tested both cases. I've created site columns within a search center and separate site collections, sadly makes no difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have encountered issues with this recently myself on at a Yammer question. You can try to clear the SharePoint Config Cache to resolve it. See  http://blogs.technet.com/b/sp/archive/2013/05/29/clear-sharepoint-config-cache-with-powershell.aspx for code on this.

Code copied from the above post:

```
Add-PSSnapin -Name Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell –erroraction SilentlyContinue

Stop-Service SPTimerV4
$folders = Get-ChildItem C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\SharePoint\Config 
foreach ($folder in $folders)
    {
    $items = Get-ChildItem $folder.FullName -Recurse
    foreach ($item in $items)
        {
            if ($item.Name.ToLower() -eq "cache.ini")
                {
                    $cachefolder = $folder.FullName
                }

        }
    }
$cachefolderitems = Get-ChildItem $cachefolder -Recurse
    foreach ($cachefolderitem in $cachefolderitems)
        {
            if ($cachefolderitem -like "*.xml")
                {
                   $cachefolderitem.Delete()
                }

        }

$a = Get-Content  $cachefolder\cache.ini
$a  = 1
Set-Content $a -Path $cachefolder\cache.ini

read-host "Do this on all your SharePoint Servers - and THEN press ENTER" 
start-Service SPTimerV4
```

Comment: Do you know what? It worked. Thanks allot!

Comment: I have a number of folders in ProgramData/Microsoft/SharePoint/Config with Guids as their names. only one has cache.ini in it.  Can I delete the rest ?

Comment: @NigelPrice I would keep them just to make sure you don't break anything - no expert on this.

Comment: Had the same problem: new custom managed property was completely ignored even after a full crawl (message in ULS was: "Didn't find property with name XXX in schema id 0 for tenant XXX site collection XXX". What did the trick was a config cache cleaning (as per this answer) + "re-index site" from site settings + incremental crawl.